# Remove whitespace from QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

A simple one for some I you I hope but I can't find it in the documentation.

```
uiText << text->toPlainText();
```

This is how I get the text from a QTextEdit.

How do I remove any whitespace?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the [QString documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html).  You weren't specific about which whitespace you want to remove, but `trimmed` or `simplified` may do what you need.

Comment: Perfect, but as you didn't put it as an answer, I can't give it the green tick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QString` has two methods for removing whitespace from a string.

`uiText << text->toPlainText().trimmed();`

would remove any whitespace at the beginning and end of the string, while

`uiText << text->toPlainText().simplified();`

would remove any whitespace at the beginning and end of the string and also reduce each sequence of whitespace inside the string to one space per occurrence.

The [QString documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html) has example of both.